# Symmetric tensor of highest weight modules for $\mathrm{SU}(2)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, modules

Let $V_i$ be the $(i+1)$-dimensional representation of the special unitary group $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ with the highest weight $i$. Is there any uniform way to compute the irreducible decomposition for the $n$-th symmetric tensor representation $S^n(V_i)$? When $i=1$, it is well known that $V_1$ is the standard representation of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, and $S^n(V_1)$ is isomorphic to $V_n$. However, what if $i\neq1$?

For example, when $i=3$, how to obtain the irreducible decomposition for $S^n(V_3)$? I use an online tool to compute the case when $1\leq n\leq 6$, and it shows $S^1(V_3)\cong V_3$ (obviously), $S^2(V_3)\cong V_6\oplus V_2$, $S^3(V_3)\cong V_9\oplus V_5\oplus V_3$, $S^4(V_3)\cong V_{12}\oplus V_8\oplus V_6\oplus V_4\oplus V_0$, $S^5(V_3)\cong V_{15}\oplus V_{11}\oplus V_9\oplus V_7\oplus V_5\oplus V_3$, and $S^6(V_3)\cong V_{18}\oplus V_{14}\oplus V_{12}\oplus V_{10}\oplus V_8\oplus V_6\oplus V_6\oplus V_2$. Notice that when $i=6$, the decomposition is no longer multiplicity-free. I cannot find any rule among these irreducible components.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The multiplicities of $V_e$ inside $n$-th symmetric power of $V_d$ are given by the Cayley-Sylvester formula
$$
P(n,d;\frac{nd-e}{2}) - P(n,d;\frac{nd-e}{2}-1)
$$
where $P(n,d;k)$ denotes the number of partitions of size $k$ inside the rectangle $n \times d$.

As the name suggests, it is very classical. For reference see e.g.  Springer T. A., Invariant theory, Lecture Notes in Mathematics 585, Springer-Verlag 1977.
There is a generalization by [Manivel](https://hal.science/hal-00330596) that treats little bit more general plethysms defined by rectangle partitions.